# Why is a warning thrown when writing a minus symbol?

Tags: warnings

I created the following minimal LaTeX document:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ansinew]{inputenc}

\begin{document}
$–A + B$
\end{document}
```

It throws a warning `'LaTeX Warning: Command \textendash invalid in math mode on input line 6'`. Without the minus symbol before the `A` everything works fine.

**Question:** Why does the minus symbol throw such a warning? I am confused.

**System:** Windows 8 64 Bit Pro, latext Miktex release with Texniccenter.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It is not a `minus` symbol but `–` that is taken as `\textendash`. Use `-` to get correct math `minus`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ansinew]{inputenc}

\begin{document}
$-A + B$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. So I somehow managed to type in the wrong symbol? I use `ansinew` because I always thought Windows uses this one, too. Should I better use `utf8` on Windows?

Comment: @HarishKumar I'd say that the options argument for `inputenc` depends on the editor being used, not the language. It should always match the character encoding the `.tex` file has been saved as.

Comment: @daleif You are correct. Thanks for correcting me. I have no idea of how John saved his file. :-)